# When to use Restoration Potions

Tags: werewolv.es

If you have a Restoration Potion, should you use it on the same night you use your single-use ability so that it will be refreshed for you the following night, or do you need to cast the potion on the night following using your action so that the power is restored for the night after using the potion?

e.g.

N2: use ability, use resto pot // N3: use ability again

OR

N2: use ability // N3: use resto pot // N4: use ability again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Restoration Potion can be cast on the SAME NIGHT that you use your ability, so that it will be refreshed for the next night.

e.g.  N2: use ability, use resto pot // N3: use ability again

You do not need to wait to cast the potion the following night.  Therefore it is possible to use your ability(ies) on two consecutive nights.

The potion refreshes all single-use abilities, for example both the witch's kill and revive potions will be restored.